# T-SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a script that is currently importing data from one table and inserting in to another table. Now I have to modify the script in such a way that if the value of the field is A then the code must appear in the column 10 else if B then the code should appear in Column 50.

Table 1:

```
Id Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 Field 4 
1            A 
2            B
```

Table 2:

```
Id Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 Field 4....Field 10.....Field 50
1                                      0/Null 
2                                                     1
```

Could anyone suggest me a case statement to implement this requirement.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Thank You, New Bee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the T-SQL with case statement which is:

```
` 
  Create table #T(
 col1 int,   col2 varchar(2),    col3 int,   col4 int,   col5 int,   col6 int,   col7 int,   col8 int,
     col9 int, col10 int,    col11 int)
     GO

 Create table #T1(
   col1 int,      col2 varchar(2),   col3 int,   col4 int,   col5 int,   col6 int,   col7 int,   col8 int,
     col9 int,   col10 int,  col11 int,  )

      Insert into #t
      Select 1,'B',5,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null union all
      Select 2,'A',5,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null union all
      Select 112,'B',5,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null union all
      Select 41,'B',5,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null union all
     Select 15,'A',5,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null


     Select * from #t

       Insert into #t1
       Select col1, col2, col3,col4,col5,col6,col7, col8
       col9,CASE WHEN COL2 ='A' Then Col2 Else 'B' End col10, col11
       from #t
 `
```

Comment: Thank you so much Maverick for an elaborated answer.It worked great for a new bee like me!!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a case expression when selecting the data: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 2):

On the insert for `Field 10` you can use a `CASE` statement, i.e.

```
CASE Field2 WHEN 'A' THEN '0\Null' ELSE '' END
```

and similarly for your `Field 50`